# How is % implemented in java?

Tags: java, module, native

I have been following [Modulus for Mersenne's Prime](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml#exmod7) and written following two methods:

First Method :

```
mersneMod(int x){
  while(x > 7){
    x = (x & 7) + (x >> 3);
  }
 return x == 7 ? 0 : x;
}
```

Second Method:

```
mod(int x){
  return x % 7;
}
```

When I bench mark these two method against numbers from `0 to 9000000`
I get following numbers:

```
Method 1 : 65784647 ns
Method 2 : 2901699 ns
```

So far, I have been thinking method 1 should be faster but it is not. Can anyone explain what's going on inside `%` operator of java. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think method 1 should be faster than method 2?

Comment: Step A) compare byte code ... step B) you read and understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java ... and you are sure that your numbers are really meaningful?

Comment: fast analysis: 3 lines of code vs. 1 line of code; 2 conditionals and 3 operations against 1 operation; a loop vs. a single simple statement - at least 3 hints that method 1 should **not** be faster.